# html5 local storage on SD card

Tags: html, local-storage, sd-card

HI!
I have searched a lot, but I didn't find the answer to this question: Is there any possibility to save or set the html5 local storage on SD card or locally on device? Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think the Local Storage API lets you decide the physical location of the data being stored. It just lets you store key/value pairs in the user’s browser via JavaScript, like a cookie except that it stays local and isn’t transmitted to the server.

The browser might choose to put its local storage data onto an SD card, or the device that it’s running on, but you don’t get to inspect the physical location of the data.

See http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html#localstorage for a good guide on what local storage can do, and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I saw this pdf [link](http://svn.aksw.org/papers/2011/ESWC_OntoWiki_Mobile/public.pdf) and I thought it is possible somehow

Comment: @Roxana: you’re very welcome! (Voting up/accepting my answer, using the arrow and tick buttons next to it, are great ways to show your appreciation on Stack Overflow :) ). Which part of the document made you think local storage could specify where the data should be stored? I noticed figure 1 shows an SD card; I think that’s just illustrative of where the data might end up. Browsers supporting local storage can run on devices that don’t have SD card slots (e.g. most laptops, the iPhone), so the actual storage device is abstracted away.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api

I do belive this is what you would need. Read support is done and there are some chrome extensions that take advantage of it (write space), however the apps don't have write support because chrome dosen't have the api, because its still wip. The chrome folks are doing a nice job with it and I think its mostly done. I've been searching around for examples.